# How to disable recyclerview scroll on touch?

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that I only want to control the scrolling by tab navigation instead of onTouchListener. So I still want it to scroll but not by touch.  Also I have a nested carousel so I don't want to disable the nested scroll listener. Is there a way to do this?